# Unable to update Microsoft Edge

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I recently noticed that my version of Microsoft Edge is out of date, and as such have been trying to update it. However, no matter what I search for online, or in the browser options, I am unable to find anything indicating how to update. In my searches, I've seen Microsoft claim that updates for Edge should be downloaded via the Windows Update utility, but it doesn't seem to be working.

My current version of Microsoft Edge is `Microsoft Edge 20.10240.16384.0`, not that I fully understand what that means or how to works.

If it's of any help, I recall having to modify core files a while back to reset/fix a small bug (I do not recall what it was) in Edge.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. How do you know it is out of date? Can you tell us what research you have done to find a solution? Have you tried to reinstall Edge from the [Download Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48126)?

Comment: I know it's out of date because I tried using something complicated in SVG that wouldn't work, and upon a bit of research I saw that it was supposed to work. I compared with a coworker, and the version of their browser is a larger/different number. Afterwards I did some Googling, and found what version number I'm supposed to have. As for the Download Center, that appears to only download a .docx file explaining Microsoft Edge's features, and not anything ultimately useful (unless I missed something).

Comment: Well, MS strikes again. Didn't realize the download was a document. Regardless, maybe it is time to troubleshoot Windows Update. Have you looked at the update history to see if it has tried to download and install that update? If it has failed, that may give you some reason why. Another option would be to run the [System File Checker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/using-system-file-checker-in-windows-10) to verify integrity of the system.

Comment: I checked the update history, and there is no mention anywhere of any updates for Microsoft Edge outside of the occasional (and successful) update of Flash for Microsoft Edge.
Additionally, after running the System File Checker, no errors were found anywhere.

Comment: 10240.16384 is the July 2015 version of Windows 10. Update to VErsion 1511 (November update) to get a newer Edge version

Comment: @magicandre1981 That's the problem though, how?

Comment: which windows 10 edition do you use? Can't you see version 1511 in Windows Update (settings app)? if you can't see the 1511 update, try to download the 1511 ISO, mount the ISO, run setup and select upgrade(keep all apps/settings): https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench

Comment: @magicandre1981 Well, this morning I got the update to version 1511, and that seems to have fixed it. Weirdly, my coworkers that have the most of to date version of Microsoft Edge do not have 1511 yet.

Comment: @Chaosxmk - That isn't possible.  Edge is directly connected to the current build of Windows 10, 10586, or Version 1511.  Which is the reason the only build of Windows that will have a version of Edge that supports extensions is the Anniversary Edition, or specifically the RS_1 branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updates to Microsoft Edge (and all other parts of Windows) are handled exclusively through the Windows Update system that is part of the Windows 10 operating system. They will be bundled in with other various updates that come through periodically.

Which updates you receive depends on which "Update ring" you are in. For most people, they are on the Release ring. Windows Insiders can choose between two further options: the Slow ring or the Fast ring.

The latest update was released to the public on **April 12th, 2016** (not even a full day before you posted your question). In this case, the update was released at the same time for all rings. As updates to Windows 10 push out in batches (and can propagate directly from machine to machine), it's likely that some users will receive updates a little sooner than others.

---

**Update** - The Creators Update, codenamed Redstone 2, scheduled for public release on April 25th, 2017, also includes an update to Microsoft Edge. Windows Insiders received the update early, as per usual, by up to two weeks.